# Watch DOM for new elements (VanillaJS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I'm working on a Chrome extension, which parses the DOM and transforms some text nodes based on certain criteria. I am using pure Javascript, i.e. no jQuery or another framework, and I want to keep it that way.

How can I watch the DOM for new dynamically inserted elements, so I can run my parser on them too?

Again, please don't suggest any jQuery solutions, or solutions using anything but pure Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting modern browsers, then you should be using [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). To do something when new node is inserted into the document, you would have code:

```
var domInsertionObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutation){
  for (var node = 0; node < mutation.addedNodes.length; node++) { 
    //do what you need to do with the added nodes
  }
});
domInsertionObserver.observe(document, { childList: true });
```

Comment: It looks like `subtree: true` should be added to the configuration for the observer to listen to changes to the entire `document` tree, not only `document`'s immediate children.

Comment: Also, the callback function receives an array of mutation objects, not a single object as show in the example.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer actually doesn't work, for a couple of reasons (explained below).

Instead, I would suggest this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(addedNode) {
      // Do things to `addedNode` here
    });
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

...because, as miniml correctly points out, `subtree: true` is required to receive events for elements added that aren't direct children, and the arguments passed to the listener callback is an **array** of `MutationRecord`s.

Also, I've chosen `document.body` as my observation root since I don't think listening for elements dynamically inserted into `<head>` is something most people are interested in. (But if that *is* desired, then just replace `document.body` with `document.documentElement` or just `document`.)

*Fun side note: in the accepted answer, the only time that listener would ever actually fire at all would be if someone literally removed the `<html>` element and/or re-created it afterward. That's it. (Because the document object is [only allowed to have one Element child](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#document-element).)*